# RestAssured: 'no supported Content-Type was specified in response. Content-Type was 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'' for content type that has support

Tags: rest, content-type, rest-assured

I'm expecting an error on a server for this request, I'm going to compare it then as a string with expected response.

```
return given()
                .queryParams(incorrectParams)
                .when()
                .put("https://example.com/endpoint")
                .then()
                .statusCode(500)
                .extract().body().as(String.class)
```

The issue is that RestAssured gives me an error when executing this: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse object because no supported Content-Type was specified in response. Content-Type was 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'.**

I've added decoder to setup but it won't help.

```
RestAssured.config().decoderConfig(new DecoderConfig(ContentType.HTML.withCharset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))));
```

The type returned by server in error case is: Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1

I additionally had seen in debbuger that default decoder should support such responses.

One more thing to mention - if request is send with correct parameters in queryParams then Content-Type: application/json is returned and everything goes fine for positive test cases.

**How to handle (extract) such a response correctly? What should be set up on a Rest Assured side?**

Rest-assured version is 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me with correct decoding was

```
                .extract().body().asPrettyString();
```

However I believe that there should be more appropriate way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to save response as String, you can do this.

```
.then()
.statusCode(500)
.extract().asString()
```

Comment: That helped me to save response as a String without error, but did not help with correct decoding. I had &#39; instead of ' symbol. What actually helped with correct decoding was .extract().body().asPrettyString() , however I believe that there should be more appropriate way to solve the issue